# How to find macros in an Excel timeline template?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a timeline with Excel 2010 and I found a very useful template from Microsoft's templates. I have provided the link to the template below.

This particular template is good but not perfect for my needs. I wish to gain access to the macros and see how they work.

So far I have been unable to see/edit/find the macros anywhere. I have been able to unhide a sheet called 'calcs' which tells me more about how the template works. However, I still can't locate the macros.

VBA editor and the in-built Excel macro list shows plain blank -- it appears that there are no macros to be found.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated!

A link to the template in question:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/results.aspx?qu=timeline&queryid=3726066d-7417-45fb-b4f4-89402dc86446#ai:TC102930043

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no macros in this template.
The `=GridCalc` is a named function 
You can access this window by clicking `Formulas` tab then `Name Manager`
It gives you access to all them named functions and their body/context.
You can create your own, edit the existing ones, etc.
Hope this helps

---

[image: Name Manager]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is how it seems to be but if you open the hidden sheet called 'calcs' from the format option menu, there is something called GridCalc on column H row 34. I am no expert but it does sound much like a macro to me. I do not understand how this template would work without some VBA -- if it does would you care to elaborate how?

Comment: That GridCalc is not how you would call a macro in VBA / Excel. That is the syntax for a named range. However if you look in the ranges drop down there is no named range called "GridCalc" in that spreadsheet, so that is why it says "#N/A".

Comment: My thanks to mehow and Vicky for helping me out. I now understand how the template works. It wasn't the macros making the magic happen.